# using environment variables from a jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

i have a little problem.

Our setup consists of 1 Master Jenkins and 2 Slaves, both Slaves use a different SVN Location String, which we saved in an Environment Variable... but both of them start the same .dll for a Test - Now my problem is that when i use `%SVN_Location%` that it takes the Environment Variables from the computer i run the build (the master).

So my question is there a way to tell him somehow to execute the `%SVN_Location%` not on the computer where the build starts, but on the computer where the slave runs

Answer (score 2):

- Use **[EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** to record the value you want to file
- Use **[Copy To Slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin)** to move the file to slave
- User EnvInject on slave to load value to environment variables, before the SCM step

Comment: Thats a workaround that may work in some cases, but not in mine, as the Master Node doesnt / shouldnt know the location of the SVN on the slave node. Here a little example: %SVN_Location_Testplace1%\Jenkins\XUnit\xunit.console.x86.exe %SVN_Location_Testplace1%\Output\Release\XUnit_DMGuiTest.dll -nologo -failskips -xml Test_DMGuiTest.xml -quiet -trait "DataManager=LocalNet" |||| So the Master shouldnt think about which location the slaves sets on his machine, to be independent and so everyone can run it on their machine by simply setting the env variable right to their location

Answer (score 0):

I managed it myself after some more Research to actually get the Environment Variable directly from the Slave and use it as a Parameter for the Master Node.

With the Plugin **[Dynamic Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in#DynamicParameterPlug-in-PluginInformation)** by using a Dynamic Parameter and the Default Value Script: `System.getenv("SVN_Location_TP1")` and the checkbox `Remote Script` checked.

[image]

When starting the build with parameters now, it automatically loads via remote script the Environment Variable from the slave and uses it as a parameter for the jenkins execution, which can be used with %SVN_Location_TP1% (in my example)